# Problems after commenting out "using namespace std;"

Tags: gcc, namespaces, c++14, using-directives, return-type-deduction

I'm new to C++ and I read that "using namespace std;" is considered bad practice. I used the following code to test if my compiler was c++14 compliant:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
auto add([](auto a, auto b){ return a+b ;});
auto main() -> int {cout << add("We have C","++14!"s);}
```

No errors. Then I started to play around with the code – as you do... when you learn something new. So I commented out `using namespace std;` and replaced `cout` with `std::cout`. Now the code looked like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//using namespace std;
auto add([](auto a, auto b){ return a+b ;});
auto main() -> int {std::cout << add("We have C","++14!"s);}
```

Build Messages:

```
||=== Build: Release in c++14-64 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\CBProjects\c++14-64\c++14-64-test.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\CBProjects\c++14-64\c++14-64-test.cpp|5|error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""s' with 'const char [6]', 'long long unsigned int' arguments|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

**Questions:**

- What causes the error in the second program?
- How to avoid `using namespace std` in this case?

Comment: It's the `s` suffix on the string literal, not `cout`. `using std::operator""s`

Comment: @Ryan `using namespace std::string_literals;` is the more conventional approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clang++` gives a good error message:

```
error: no matching literal operator for call to 'operator""s' with arguments of types 'const char *' and 'unsigned long', and no matching literal operator template
auto main() -> int { std::cout << add("We have C", "++14!"s); }
                                                          ^
```

You use string literals and more precisely [`operator""s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

By removing `using namespace std;` you have to specify the namespace where the operator is defined.

With an explicit call:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << add("We have C", std::operator""s("++14!", 5));
  // Note the length of the raw character array literal is required
}
```

or with a `using` declaration:

```
int main() {
  using std::operator""s;
  std::cout << add("We have C", "++14!"s);
}
```

Comment: Prefer `using namespace std::string_literals`.